# How to set up logging for aiohttp.client when making request with aiohttp.ClientSession()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have some code making sequence of requests to some API. I'd like to set up common logging for all, how can I set this up?

Let's say my code looks like this

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(client):
    async with client.get('http://httpbin.org/get') as resp:
        assert resp.status == 200
        return await resp.text()

async def post_data(client):
    async with client.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data={'foo': 'bar'}) as resp:
        assert resp.status == 200
        return await resp.text()

async def main(loop):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as client:
        html = await fetch(client)
        print(html)
        other_html = await post_data(client)
        print(other_html)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

Now I'd like to see status code, url, headers and all for all requests made, so output in logs looking like this:

```
2017-08-09 08:44:30 DEBUG (200) <GET http://httpbin.org/get>
2017-08-09 08:44:30 DEBUG (200) <POST http://httpbin.org/post>
```

I know I could add logger.log() call after every request, but that'll be duplication. If I have more requests I will have to write duplicate code under every request making call to logger.log. Seems inefficient.

There is [aiohttp.client logger](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html), but there are no details how to set it up.

I'm trying to set it up like this

```
logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
logging.getLogger('aiohttp.client').addHandler(ch)
```

but it doesn't print information that I'd like to see (e.g. response status code, url).

Is there some way to achieve what I need? Perhaps I can subscribe to some signal from client and log some message when signal is sent? E.g. have some mechanism to subscribe to signal sent when client receive response and then log message on that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can see in aiohttp's code, the aiohttp.client logger is not used to log requests, but can only log a warning if the cookies in the response are invalid
https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=client_logger&type=

To log every requests you are doing, you will need to create a custom `ClientSession` that does what you want. Something like:

```
class LoggingClientSession(aiohttp.ClientSession):
    def request(self, method, url, **kwargs):
        logger.debug('Starting request <%s %r>', method, url)
        return super().request(method, url, **kwargs)
```

-

As noted by Jaanus in the comments here, the `post`, `get`, … helpers now call `ClientSession._request` directly, instead of `request`. So overriding the later won't intercept calls made with the short-hand helpers.

So you can either:

- override `_request` instead of `request` in your helper
- or make sure your code never uses the `get`/… helpers and always calls `request` directly.
- or also define all the helper methods in your `LoggingClientSession`

-

And as noted by Romuald, `_request` is now a coroutine, so overriding it with a regular function will not log at exactly the right time. Here is an updated example:

```
class LoggingClientSession(aiohttp.ClientSession):
    async def _request(self, method, url, **kwargs):
        logger.debug('Starting request <%s %r>', method, url)
        return await super()._request(method, url, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Great for wrapping it inside a class. very clean!

Comment: It looks like `request` has been renamed `_request`.

Comment: @JeremyBanks No, `_request` is an aiohttp internal that should not be modified. the `request` method still exists and can be used to intercept all requests. cf https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/client.py#L139

Comment: Even though internal, it's useful to override `_request` instead of `request` because session methods such as `get`, `post`, etc are all going through the former instead of the latter. But as @Arthur mentioned, it is a slippery slope and can change from version to version.

Comment: Unfortunately this is somewhat inaccurate. Trying to debug when aiohttp is actually making the request, this method will log the query as soon as the request coroutine is created, not when the request is actually made

Comment: In the latest aiohttp, `_request` is a coroutine. So you can override it with a coroutine and the log will be made only when the request is actually awaited. It won't be exactly when the request is sent, but I don't think the distinction meaningful. I have updated my comment to define a coroutine

Comment: Note that `aiohttp.ClientSession` is not intended to be extended and doing so issues a warning now: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3185

Comment: IMO, it is pretty lame on the aiohttp's side not to provide a hook for one of the most commonly used feature for debugging. Other language HTTP clients provide some way of intercepting the request before it goes out on the wire without having to hack "private" methods.

Answer (score 18):

At the time of writing (11/2020) you should use [tracing functionality of aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/tracing_reference.html):

```
import asyncio
import logging
import aiohttp


async def on_request_start(session, context, params):
    logging.getLogger('aiohttp.client').debug(f'Starting request <{params}>')


async def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    trace_config = aiohttp.TraceConfig()
    trace_config.on_request_start.append(on_request_start)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trace_configs=[trace_config]) as session:
        await session.get('https://google.com')


asyncio.run(main())
```